# kmeans clustering groups the data vertically rather than horizontally

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset like this:

```
coupled_series = [(9.752, 0.0005), (9.9792, 0.0008), (9.8571, 0.0036), (10.5017, 0.0038), (10.4808, 0.0038), (10.6975, 0.003), (12.1378, 0.0008), (12.7328, 0.0005), (14.0357, 0.0035), (11.7431, 0.0039), (10.107, 0.0039), (10.4207, 0.0039), (10.563, 0.003), (11.0856, 0.0009), (11.3304, 0.0005), (11.87, 0.0035), (12.9338, 0.0039), (13.243, 0.0039), (13.4354, 0.0038), (13.14, 0.003), (13.4611, 0.0008), (13.1459, 0.0004), (11.956, 0.0035), (12.4869, 0.0039), (13.2369, 0.004), (13.6368, 0.0039), (14.11, 0.0029), (14.1441, 0.0007), (13.8937, 0.0004), (13.4262, 0.0007)]
```

I like to run a kmeans cluster using sklearn using following code:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, max_iter=50, n_init="auto", random_state=0, algorithm='lloyd')
kmeans.fit(coupled_series)


x=list(zip(*coupled_series))[0]
y=list(zip(*coupled_series))[1]

plt.scatter(x, y, c=kmeans.labels_)
plt.show()
```

the result is the following picture:
[image]

As you can see, it has clustered the groups into left and right while one can say by looking at it that it's consisting of two lines on top and bottom. i.e., I would like them to be clustered into two groups of red and blue like picture below.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this to cluster the way I like? Are there any other options of types of clustering I can try? Just to mention that I need to repeat this to other groups of data too and they mostly look like this.

Comment: You can swap the x and y axis to make the look of the plot change but what is the difference in the way it is plottted?

Comment: Those are the same plots. I just mean I would like it to be clustered like the circles in the below plot. Also x and y doesn't matter. @JesseSealand

Comment: Do you want all of the yellow points on top and all of the purple points on the bottom?

Comment: yes that's correct @JesseSealand

Comment: Yes. So swap the x and y axis and it'll rotate your graph 90 degrees. The yellow will be on top and the purple will be on the bottom.

Comment: The clustering that you are seeing is most likely due to the very different scales of the two axes. You should therefore probably apply some normalisation, e.g., https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler, to the data first.

Comment: @MattPitkin Although scaling helped with this particular dataset, when there are only a few points in between, it returns previous result. Try adding only one datapoints (11, 0.0020) to the coupled_series and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I think you'll just have to live with that if you want to use KMeans. Otherwise, you could try a different clustering method, such as a Gaussian Mixture model https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply some normalisation/scaling to your data, e.g., the [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler). For example, if you do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

coupled_series = [(9.752, 0.0005), (9.9792, 0.0008), (9.8571, 0.0036), (10.5017, 0.0038), (10.4808, 0.0038), (10.6975, 0.003), (12.1378, 0.0008), (12.7328, 0.0005), (14.0357, 0.0035), (11.7431, 0.0039), (10.107, 0.0039), (10.4207, 0.0039), (10.563, 0.003), (11.0856, 0.0009), (11.3304, 0.0005), (11.87, 0.0035), (12.9338, 0.0039), (13.243, 0.0039), (13.4354, 0.0038), (13.14, 0.003), (13.4611, 0.0008), (13.1459, 0.0004), (11.956, 0.0035), (12.4869, 0.0039), (13.2369, 0.004), (13.6368, 0.0039), (14.11, 0.0029), (14.1441, 0.0007), (13.8937, 0.0004), (13.4262, 0.0007)]

# apply minmax scaling to each axes to "normalise" things
scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(coupled_series)

kmeans = KMeans(
    n_clusters=2,
    max_iter=50,
    n_init="auto",
    random_state=0,
    algorithm="lloyd"
)
kmeans.fit(scaled)

x=list(zip(*coupled_series))[0]
y=list(zip(*coupled_series))[1]

plt.scatter(x, y, c=kmeans.labels_)
plt.show()
```

Then you should get a plot like:

[image]